# Cannot raise hand in Zoom

Tags: 20.04, zoom-meeting

I cannot raise and/or lower my hand in any Zoom meetings.

I have tried:

1. Downloading Zoom from the Ubuntu store and as a .deb package from the website.
2. No buttons in the Participants section
3. Shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> does not do anything
4. Zoom is updated to the latest version 5.4.3

None of these worked, and this is certainly a problem with Zoom, not Ubuntu, I just want to ask here because I believe someone might help out from the community.

Answer (score 3):

I actually solved the problem. Now raise hand works but only when the window is completely full screen or small windowed. Does not work with the "full screen but you see the dock and the top bar mode" (don't know the actual name) which is the mode I normally use, but making the window smaller when I want to raise my hand is not that bad. Turns out I should have tried that before I wrote here. Thanks for your help.

P.S the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> shortcut also dos not work- but that is a software issue that cannot be resolved here again thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your zoom version is below 5.5.0 - Click on Participants. There are 3 dots (...) on the lower right side of this window. Click on the three dots and click 'Raise Hand' / 'Lower Hand'

On version 5.5.0+, Raise Hand is available on the main screen itself under Reactuions

Comment: I currently run version 5.5.7011 and "Raise Hand" is available in this participants menu but not on the main screen.